# c# list in list and incorrect instance of an object

Tags: c#

I have such structure

```
public class Agent
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

and this code

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Out);
foreach (Student stu in obj.Students)
{   
    ...
    foreach (Agent Agent in stu.Agents)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

> foreach (Agent Agent in stu.Agents)

get error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tell me how I should correctly declare objects

Comment: First, you need to check if JSON was deserialized correctly.

Comment: What is the value of `Out`? Probably it contains no agents. Have you even tried to debug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Share the JSON you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: FaizanRabbani, thanks, you are right, one of the cycles did not return agents

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Agents` list initialization in `Student` class default constructor. It will help you to handle absence of `Agents` in your JSON.

Try this.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Agent> Agents { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        Agents = new List<Agent>();
    }
}
```